# Ionic 5 IOS & Stripe Payment Request Button - Stripe.js integrations must use HTTPS

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, stripe-payments

I'm trying to add a [Payment Request Button](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/elements/payment-request-button) to my Ionic 5 app. However, no matter how I run the app, I always get the following message and the button won't show.

> [warn] - You may test your Stripe.js integration over HTTP. However,
> live Stripe.js integrations must use HTTPS.

I'm loading the Stripe API over https

```
  <script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>
```

I've imported it in to my page

```
declare var Stripe;

// Check the availability of the Payment Request API first.
const prButton = elements.create('paymentRequestButton', {
    paymentRequest,
});

paymentRequest.canMakePayment().then(result => {
   if (result) {
       prButton.mount('#payment-request-button');
   } else {
       document.getElementById('payment-request-button').style.display = 'none';
   }

);
```

I've tried running it in Safari on Mac (running with --ssl and a valid certificate), Xcode Emulator, A Real iPhone and the result is always the same.

Also worth noting is that I'm using Capacitor, not Cordova. I've tried this in my capacitor.config.json but it had no effect.

```
 "iosScheme": "https",
```

#### Update:

So it turns out that it's because the app runs with the local urlScheme of `capacitor://` rather than `https://` and the development team at Ionic currently [have no plans to rectify this](https://github.com/ionic-team/capacitor/issues/758). Is there any way to make the Payment Request Button appear in a non-https environment?

Comment: You'd want to use the native integration: https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/stripe

Comment: @ceejayoz I have tried to use this but repeatedly got undefined methods - I'm not convinced the Capacitor implementation is up to the same standard as the Cordova one - and the documentation is minimal. As far as I can tell from tutorials/guides on the internet, using the normal stripe library should also work. Do you happen to know if the native plugin supports Payment Request Buttons?

Comment: This is likely due to the fact that the local web server running on the iOS device that displays your content cannot serve pages via HTTPS with a valid certificate.  Does the `server.url` in your configuration start with `http`?  Does it break if you change it to start with `https`?

Comment: @JustinMichael Can I confirm which configuration? I don't have a server.url in my angular.json, capcacitor.config.json or my ionic.config.json

Comment: @Lewis I was asking about the `capacitor.config.json` file's `url` as documented here: https://capacitorjs.com/docs/config

Comment: Setting the url to https in the config breaks the app completely. Tried https: with both localhost and an ip address.

Comment: @Lewis did you end up finding a way to integrate Apple Pay into an Ionic app?  I am running into the same issues.  I am considering trying the Capacitor native plugin.

Comment: @MadMac I did, I'll post an answer down below when I get time later today. The short version is, I had to use an old v1 of stripes APIs and generate the tokens manually.

Comment: @Lewis Thanks that would be incredibly helpful.  In case anyone reads this in the future I did get it working using https://github.com/capacitor-community/stripe however this requires a lot more setup with apple / stripe certificates etc so my preference would be to use the web version with the payment request button

Answer (score 2):

## UPDATE 2023

3 years later and there's finally a much better solution - an npm package by the name of [@capacitor-community/stripe](https://stripe.capacitorjs.jp/)

Along with requiring the usual Apple Pay dependencies (certificates etc), it's really simple once you have the package installed;

```
import { Stripe, PaymentSheetEventsEnum } from '@capacitor-community/stripe';

// attach listener to payment completed
Stripe.addListener(PaymentSheetEventsEnum.Completed, (result) => {
   console.log('payment result', result);
   
   // code here for after payment
});

// run the code below here in a method (i.e, button press)

await Stripe.initialize({
   publishableKey: 'pk_test_#####################',
});

// get your client token from your payment intent (api)
const { paymentIntent } = await $api.get('payment-test');

// show the payment sheet
await Stripe.createPaymentSheet({
   paymentIntentClientSecret: paymentIntent,
   enableApplePay: true,
   applePayMerchantId: 'abcdefghij',
   merchantDisplayName: 'Merchant Name',
   withZipCode: false,
   countryCode: 'GB'
});

const { paymentResult } = await Stripe.presentPaymentSheet();
```

The code above produces a payment sheet like this;

[image]

===============================================================

### Original answer from 2020

After a lot of back and forth with Stripe's support team, I finally came up with a solution. A lot of what they said is included in this answer (placed in blockquotes). I've also included a code example that will hopefully help make sense of it.

> I'm absolutely aware this is quite complex but unfortunately when not
> using our official iOS SDK the process is quite involved, and as of
> right now we don't have any official support for cross-platform
> technologies like Ionic or React Native.

You must have an apple developer account, a merchant id and have a payment processing certificate uploaded to stripe (see steps 1->3 of https://stripe.com/docs/apple-pay#native)

You can use the cordova plugin (https://github.com/samkelleher/cordova-plugin-applepay#example-response) to generate an apple pay token. This will then be submitted to the V1 stripe API and exchanged for a Stripe Token. This is how Stripe's official IOS SDK works by tokenizing the PKPayment object in to a Stripe Token.

The paramaters to pass to the end point (not in the documentation) are;

- pk_token (the string that you get from base64 decoding the
  paymentData)
- pk_token_payment_netowrk (paymentMethodNetwork)
- pk_token_instrument_name (paymentMethodDisplayName)
- pk_token_transaction_id (transactionIdentifier)

The names in the brackets are what is returned when using the cordova plugin.

> Once you call this endpoint, you should get back a standard Stripe
> token object(but the request will fail if you haven't registered your
> Apple Pay payment processing cert as mentioned above). The Stripe
> token(tok_xxx) can be used for payments as normal — the easiest way is
> to convert it to a PaymentMethod by calling /v1/payment_methods with
> type=card&card[token]=tok_xxxx , and then using it to confirm a
> PaymentIntent.

Code Example

```
completeApplePay(resp){
        const _this = this;

        return new Promise((resolution, rejection) => {
            $.post({
                url: 'https://api.stripe.com/v1/tokens',
                beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                    xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer pk_test_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx")
                },
                data: {
                    pk_token: atob(resp.paymentData),
                    pk_token_payment_network: resp.paymentMethodNetwork,
                    pk_token_instrument_name: resp.paymentMethodDisplayName,
                    pk_token_transaction_id: resp.transactionIdentifier
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    resolution({
                       token: data.id
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    }
```

The (resp) parameter in the function above is the response from the cordova plugin;

```
const applePayTransaction = await this.applePayController.makePaymentRequest(order).then(resp => {
    this.stripe.completeApplePay(resp).then((stresp:any) => {
       // code goes here to store order in database etc
    })
});
await this.applePayController.completeLastTransaction('success');
```